# Help me understand my test result

Tags: research

I recently got a bloodwork done.

The ranges given were 35.0-155.0 pg/mL

My test result was 72.3,

(72.3-35)/(155-35) * 100 = 31%

Am I correct to assume that I am on the 31 percentile based on the lab result?

Comment: The ranges given are typically a "normal" range, which would suggest that (outside unusual circumstances) your physician will never be concerned about a number within that range. For numbers outside the range, they will pay more attention and even then they may or may not suggest a problem. You should ask your physician for guidance in interpreting your lab results.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is incorrect. It assumes a uniform distribution of values within the reference range, which is rarely the case. There is not enough data here to say which percentile you are in. For that, you need to know the actual distribution. This requires more research.